# css - coloring only piece of border

Tags: html, css

So I made a hollow circle with text inside, code is:

```
.numberCircle 
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    width: 512px;
    height: 512px;
    padding-top: 114px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 32px solid #000;
    color: #0099FF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jsb15yvx/2/)

How can I make for example only quarter or half (or more) of border blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can looking into using `border-top`, `border-bottom`, `border-left`, and `border-right` to style individual portions of the border itself.

You can also change the radius of each section by using `border-top-right-radius`, `border-top-left-radius`, `border-bottom-left-radius`, and ``border-bottom-right-radius`.

Here is a somewhat hackish solution that seems to give the desired result.

New HTML:

```
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="circleContent">
    3/10
    <span style="display:block;font-size:26px;color:#666;">128 credits</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

New CSS:

```
.numberCircle {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  padding: 114px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 32px solid #000;
  border-right: 32x solid #0000ff;
  border-bottom: 32px solid #0000ff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  color: #0099FF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.circleContent {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it actually worked, but how can I make like 10 pieces of it? because now I can make only 4.

Comment: If you need to use more segments and draw more complex objects, it may be worth looking into using the HTML5 canvas as it starts getting a bit too complex to do with CSS easily.